# Postfix unknown mail transport error発生原因

Tags: postfix

### 前提

新規でオンプレミスにメールサーバを構築しました。

- Postfix
- dovecot

構築したメールサーバは以下要件があります。

1. サブドメイン　xx.xxxlogistics.co.jpに関してはローカルメールボックスへ
2. xxx-logistics.co.jp を持っているドメインは O365 に転送（25 番ポート）
3. その他は、 MX レコードに従い転送

---

### 発生している問題

上記、 2 を満たすために以下の通り、 Postfix 設定を行いました。

1. `main.cf` をバックアップする。
2. `main.cf` を更新する。
3. 以下を追記

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

4. transportdb を作成する。

```
# cd /etc/postfix
# cp -p transport transport_yyyymmmdd
# vi transport
xxx-logistics.co.jp smtp:xxx-logistics.co.jp01c.mail.protection.outlook.com
```

そうした所、以下エラーがでました。原因が解る方いらっしゃいますでしょうか。

> May  9 19:04:27 localhost postfix/error[1385]: 99EF0810CD9: to=, relay=none, delay=1.3, delays=0.17/1.1/0/0.05, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (unknown mail transport error)

Comment: マルチポストなのでクローズします。失礼しました。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/125348

Comment: マルチポスト　https://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/10504

Comment: SOはマルチポストを禁止していませんし、質問を閉じてしまう必要はないです。このまま回答を受け付けて良いと思います。新しい情報があれば追加して頂ければありがたいかと。

Comment: htb さんの仰る通り、質問をクローズする理由は何ひとつないですが、 参考までに、何かしらの理由で自分から質問を終了したくなった場合には、次のメタ投稿などを参照するとよいです: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2634/754